# Update does not work... params problem I guess

Tags: ruby, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5

I could not update because of params problem I guess. Even though flash said "updated successfully" but nothing changed. I used `User` model and `Skill` model which make things more complicated.
Please tell me how to fix this situation.

Skills controller:

```
class SkillsController < UsersController
  def update  
    @skill=Skill.find_by(id:params[:id])

    if @skill.update_attributes(skills_params)
      flash[:success]="Updated Successfully"
      redirect_to users_url
    else
      flash[:danger]="no infomation"
      render @skill
    end
  end

  private

  def skills_params
    params.permit(:id,:skill_type, :tech, :web_name, :web_url, :web_image, :experience)
  end
end
```

skills/edit.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @skill do |f| %>
  <%= f.label:skill_type %>
  <%= text_field :skill_type, value=@skill.skill_type, :placeholder => 
@skill.skill_type %>

  <%= f.label:tech %>
  <%= text_field :tech, value=@skill.tech,:placeholder => @skill.tech %>

  <!-- More fields -->

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Server logs:

```
Processing by SkillsController#update as HTML
Parameters{"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"XrbQqewGHBC8yoFHFg9tkg9sCTtscV+QjUMgaw2pdXEsUk+NiCJHSHVkj/N/bhjD1uaExeop4uSXb6hCCKGD/Q==", "skill_type"=>{"0"=>"1"}, "tech"=>{"shitunnkokoko"=>"aaaa"}, "web_name"=>{"ssasdesilgffgfo"=>"aaaaaa"}, "web_url"=>{"googleeee.com"=>"aaa@aaaa"}, "web_image"=>{"dfsafsafasfasdf"=>"bbbbb"}, "experience"=>{"javaaaaaa"=>"sssss"}, "commit"=>"変更する", "id"=>"5"}
  Skill Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "skills".* FROM "skills" WHERE "skills"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :_method, :authenticity_token, :skill_type, :tech, :web_name, :web_url, :web_image, :experience, :commit
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
```

**

### Additional Information

**

skill.ruby

```
class Skill < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 # mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
 validates :user_id,presence:true
 validates :experience, length:{maximum:500}
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save {self.email = email.downcase}
  validates :name, presence:true,length:{maximum:50}
  VALID_EMAIL_FORM=/\A[a-zA-Z0-9_\#!$%&`'*+\-{|}~^\/=?\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9] 
[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\z/
  validates :email, presence:true,length:{maximum:255},
                   format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_FORM},
                   uniqueness:{ case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length:{minimum:6},presence:true

  def skills
    return Skill.find_by(user_id:self.id)
  end
end
```

skill table schema

```
sqlite> .schema skills
CREATE TABLE "skills" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT 
NULL, "skill_type" integer DEFAULT NULL, "tech" varchar DEFAULT NULL, 
"web_name" varchar DEFAULT NULL, "web_url" text DEFAULT NULL, 
"web_image" varchar DEFAULT NULL, "experience" text DEFAULT NULL, 
"created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL, 
"picture" varchar DEFAULT NULL, "user_id" integer);
CREATE INDEX "index_skills_on_user_id_and_created_at" ON "skills" 
("created_at");
CREATE INDEX "index_skills_on_user_id" ON "skills" ("user_id");
```

users table schema

```
sqlite> .schema users
CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
"name" varchar DEFAULT NULL, "email" varchar DEFAULT NULL, 
"created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL, 
"password_digest" varchar DEFAULT NULL);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_users_on_email" ON "users" ("email");
```

Comment: check out this line in your logs: `Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :_method, :authenticity_token, :skill_type, :tech, :web_name, :web_url, :web_image, :experience, :commit` All the attributes you tried to update are unpermitted.

Comment: Are you sure all the attributes of `Skill` are of Hash type? Can you post the model and DB schema?

Comment: Hash parameters are permitted as: `params.permit(:id, skill_type: ['0'], tech: [: shitunnkokoko], web_name: [:ssasdesilgffgfo], ...`

Comment: sorry for late reply. I added model and schema for User and Skill. please analyze how to fix this... Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the `@skill` is empty.

In the `edit` Action in the `SkillsController` you load `@skill` and `@user` by the same id (`id:params[:id]`)

```
@user=User.find_by(id:params[:id])
@skill=Skill.find_by(id:params[:id])
```